# DataGridCheckBoxColumn loses IsReadOnly state when applying ElementStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, readonly, elementstyle

I need to vertically center a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`. Since I did not find a Property inside `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, I applied an `ElementStyle`. However, when this style is applied, my `CheckBox` becomes checkable again, although it is set to `ReadOnly` in my `DataGrid` (the whole `Datagrid` is `ReadOnly`), and in `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` itself.

How can I create a vertically centered `CheckBox` that keeps its `ReadOnly` state? Here is my code:

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Test" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding MyBinding}">                        
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0,1,0,0" />
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />                                
                </Style>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set `ElementStyle` on the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` you should include [`FrameworkElement.IsHitTestVisible="False"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible(v=vs.110).aspx) to your `Style`:

```
<Setter Property="FrameworkElement.IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
```

Also if you add `TargetType="CheckBox"` to the `Style` then you don't have to repeat `FrameworkElement` for each `Setter` anymore:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I still don't really understand why it is necessary at all. Should changing the style really cause the readonly-property to get lost?

Comment: You should probably also set `Focusable` to `False`, so should can't edit it with the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I have a suspicion that this is a bug (as it doesn't happen on other column types).

To work around it, all you need to do is make sure you base your style on the default style; by adding `BasedOn="{x:Static DataGridCheckBoxColumn.DefaultElementStyle}"` to the `Style` element:

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Test" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding MyBinding}">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style BasedOn="{x:Static DataGridCheckBoxColumn.DefaultElementStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0,1,0,0" />
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This approach has the advantage that you don't have to do lots of work if you are intending on changing the `DataGrid.IsReadOnly` property at runtime.